# Need help making this code more efficient

Tags: java, nio

I always use this method to easily read the content of a file. Is it efficient enough? Is 1024 good for the buffer size?

```
public static String read(File file) {
    FileInputStream stream = null;
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }

    FileChannel channel = stream.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

    try {
        while (channel.read(buffer) != -1) {
            buffer.flip();

            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                str.append((char) buffer.get());
            }

            buffer.rewind();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            channel.close();
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'm not commenting on efficiency, but the swallowing of exceptions is a definite no-no, IMHO. Imagine that a `FileNotFoundException` occurs, then `stream.getChannel()` causes a NPE to be thrown.

Comment: Testing if the buffer size is ok, is merely a matter of testing, right? What happens if you make if 512, or 2048?

Comment: How are *we* supposed to know whether this method is fast enough for your purposes?

Comment: In terms of efficiency:  Measure.  Find a metric you care about (in this case, perhaps "what is the wall clock time to slurp a file into a charsequence?"), measure it to some level of statistical significance, and then ask whether your implementation meets your performance goals or not.  If it matters, find a way to measure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find that this is fast enough.

```
String text = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

AFAIK, this uses the default buffer size of 8K. However I have found larger sizes such as 64K can make a slight difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, it should work (well):

```
public static String read(File file)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader in = null;

    String line = null;

    try
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
           str.append(line);

        in.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think your use of `.available()` may be incorrect.  That method returns the number of bytes (likely to be) available without blocking the thread; it's not reliable as an indication of the bytes remaining in the stream.

Comment: @andersoj: I believe you are right. I've reworked my solution. I hope it's simpler to understand. Thanks.

Comment: It's *not* an indication of the bytes remaining in the stream. It says so explicitly in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

I would always look to FileUtils http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html to see if they had a method. In this case I would use readFileToString(File) 
http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29

They have already dealt with almost all the problem cases...

Comment: Also, Guava's implementations in `Files` are a good guidepost.  http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html